# Any way to upload DNS records to free Firebase domains?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

Firebase provide 2 free domains per project, but is it possible to upload DNS records?

I want to enable Firebase Dynamic Links. Then I need to upload DNS records but I can'T find how to do it.

Anybody knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase does not provide DNS service.  You must bring your own DNS provider.

Once you have your own DNS, you can connect it to Dynamic Links using the [instructions in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains).

If you are using Firebase Hosting, you can connect it to Firebase Hosting using the [instructions provided in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain).

Answer (score 0):

DNS services are normally provided by your domain registrar, so the company where you registered your domain. Firebase doesn't offer domain registration services, so it doesn't allow you to manage DNS records either. Check with the place where you registered your domain for how to manage the DNS for that domain too.